# Magento 2.1: Empty fields when editing migrated product

Tags: admin, magento-2.1, migration, magento-2.1.3

I've used Ubertheme's migration tool to migrate around 6,000 products from Magento 1.7 to 2.1.3.

In terms of actual data, everything appears to check out in the database or in certain areas of the admin system.

However, when I edit one of the migrated products, every field in the edit form is blank other than SKU.

It's unusual because on the main product admin page, all of the columns for each product are correctly populated.

Has anybody seen a problem like this before?

Comment: did you got any solution for this?

Comment: I wrote my own 1.7 script to export the products in XML, and then a 2.1.3 script to import them from that file.